# Question on numbers modulo $(n+1)!$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I just noticed the following surprising 'fact' (it holds at least for low values of n):

Pick any number k < $(n+1)!$

Consider the n products $ki$ with $1 \le i \le n$, i.e. $k, 2k, ... nk$ modulo $(n+1)!$.

In at least one of these cases, this modulus will at either:

- be at most $n!$, or
- be at least $(n+1)! - n!$

So basically it will lie in the range $[-n!, n!]$ modulo $(n+1)!$.

For example, let n = 5.
Here, $(n+1)! = 720$.

Pick a random number in $[0, 720]$, say $489$. We get $n = 5$ products:

- $489 * 1 \mod 720 = 489$
- $489 * 2 \mod 720 = 258$
- $489 * 3 \mod 720 = 27$
- $489 * 4 \mod 720 = 516$
- $489 * 5 \mod 720 = 285$

Although we managed to escape in four cases, with $i=3$ we ended up with a residue of $27$ which lies between $-120$ and $120$.

Any ideas on how to prove that this will always happen? Or maybe a counter-example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the pigeonhole principle.

Add the number $0$, There are 2 numbers which differ by at most $(n+1)!/(n+1)=n!$

Their difference gives you a number within the range $ [-n!, n!]$

Comment: Thanks, it looks simple in hindsight :)